# Conditionally Render A Lightning Quick Action?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, quickaction, conditional

I've have a component that implements force:lightningQuickAction but would like to have conditional rendering (i.e only display on the page layout if a bool field == true). I've been researching, but have not found a way to conditionally render within a standard component?  Does anyone know if this is possible, or if a parent component is the only way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the challenge is to conditionally show a component on a page layout based on a field value, you can do it starting winter 18 using "set component visibility" in your app builder.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_dynamic_pages.htm

Comment: I understand that you can conditionally render a component in the new release, but if you would like the component to display as a quick action is there a way to conditionally display the action within the component without hiding the entire component without creating a parent component?

Comment: Assuming you have control over the component, why not call the quickactionclose event when the user clicks the button based on the user profiles you want to restrict ???